# What does the generic type in modifier mean in the Java Documentation?

Tags: java

Can anyone tell me what the <T> means in the capture below??
I don't get why the access modifier should have a generic type information.
Thanks for all your help in advance.

[image: Java Documentation capture]

Comment: *"the access modifier should have a generic type information"*: which "access modifier" are you referring to (none is shown)? `<T>` is about the method being generic, and it has **a** correct place in the method declaration. Is that what your question is about?

Comment: Read about "generic methods".  The `<T>` is a type parameter for the method, not for the access modifier.  Also, `static` is not an access modifier.

Comment: Do you know what [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) are in Java?

Comment: @Abra, lots of people know about "generic types", and think they know all there is to know about generics.  They don't necessarily know about the other side of the coin - "generic methods".

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem do you mean [Generic Methods and Bounded Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/boundedTypeParams.html)?

Comment: what is the different between normal List<T> vs  <T> List<T>  in the documentation?

Comment: @BabyishTank `<T> List<T>` is not a type. It is a type parameter for a method (declaring that the method signature will use a type parameter named T) followed by a `List<T>`.

Comment: (and I should have said "declaring that the method will use..." as the type parameter can be used in the method body as well)

Comment: Oh, I didn't know the concept "type parameter". I must have passed the concept "generic methods" when learning. Thanks all for answering. The following [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/where-exactly-type-parameter-need-to-be-specified-while-declaring-generic-method-in-java) helped.